# How can I detect zero denominator when reading Ratios?

Tags: haskell

I want to read a Ratio from a String, but I don't want my program to crash when the denominator is zero. How can I detect a zero denominator and avoid an error? Just using `readMaybe` doesn't work:

```
Prelude Text.Read> readMaybe "1 % 0" :: Maybe Rational
Just *** Exception: Ratio has zero denominator
```

I created this far from perfect solution:

```
readMaybeRational :: String -> Maybe Rational
readMaybeRational s =
  case ((readMaybe $ drop 1 $ dropWhile (/='%') s) :: Maybe Int)
    of Just 0 -> Nothing
       _ -> readMaybe s
```

But I don't know how to handle a nested Ratio nicely:

```
"Just (1 % 0)"
```

If I could override Ratio's Read instance, I could get readMaybe to return Nothing when the denominator is zero:

```
instance (Integral a, Read a) => Read (Ratio a) where
  readPrec =
    parens
    ( prec ratioPrec
      ( do x <- step readPrec
           expectP (L.Symbol "%")
           y <- step readPrec
           -- is y 0? If so, do something here
           return (x % y)
      )
    )
```

But I'm pretty sure I can't do that.

Comment: Honestly, seems like a bug that it doesn't just give a parse failure. [It's specified in the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch22.html#:~:text=readsPrec,]%29) that it really does cause an exception, but... the Haskell report is far from perfect. You could ask the library maintainers to fix it anyway.

Comment: There is no simple way to fix this I can see. One would need to use a `newtype` to defined the fixed parser, then use that everywhere. This would require to make it inherit all the operations of `Ratio`. If we then need to use a library that wants the standard `Ratio`, we need to perform the conversion, which is cumbersome if the type is deeply nested, and could be impossible if the nesting is opaque (under a non exported constructor).

Comment: I think if you defined your own type `newtype MaybeNum a = MaybeNum { getMaybeNum :: Maybe a }`, and gave it all the right instances, you could parse a value of type `Ratio (MaybeNum a)`, and then convert that to your `Ratio a`. Then in the instances for `MaybeNum` you could catch the zero denominator. This would also let you use the actual `Read` instance.

Comment: @oisdk I don't think that would work. In particular, wouldn't that prevent the numerator from being zero too?

Comment: Not necessarily, I think. You could catch the zero numerator inside the function `catchZeroDenom :: Ratio (MaybeNum a) -> Maybe (Ratio a)`. i.e. you'd swap out `Nothing` for `0` in that case. I think that what I'm proposing is actually just a worse version of @chi 's solution, though.

Comment: @oisdk Would `3 - 3 :: MaybeNum Int` be `MaybeNum (Just 0)` or `MaybeNum Nothing`? How about `MaybeNum (Just 0) + MaybeNum Nothing`? No matter what you decide, isn't it going to violate at least one of the customary laws?

Comment: Hmm so it's more complex than I thought! :) I suppose you could have a smart constructor which checks for zero, and use that (so you could assume you'll never get a `Just 0`). In lens terms, it would be [`non 0`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:non)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best solution is a `newtype` wrapper around `Ratio`, like this:

```hs
import Control.Monad
import GHC.Read
import GHC.Real
import qualified Text.Read.Lex as L
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec

newtype SaneReadRatio a = SaneReadRatio (Ratio a)
type SaneReadRational = SaneReadRatio Integer

instance (Integral a, Read a) => Read (SaneReadRatio a) where
  readPrec =
    parens
    ( prec ratioPrec
      ( do x <- step readPrec
           expectP (L.Symbol "%")
           y <- step readPrec
           guard (y /= 0)
           return (SaneReadRatio (x % y))
      )
    )

  readListPrec = readListPrecDefault
  readList     = readListDefault
```

Use it by reading in your data with `SaneReadRational` in place of `Rational`, then using `coerce` from `Data.Coerce` on the result, which will change it back to the underlying `Rational` no matter how deeply it's buried inside your type.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you